# Is this an error in Mathematica 9?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This code in Mathematica 9 returns two graphs that are NOT complementary.

```
{GraphData[{7, 172}], GraphData[{7, 172}, "ComplementGraph"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the mapping presented in [Feyre's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129442/31159), it is possible to check that those two graphs are complementary by generating the complement of the first graph, and verifying that it is isomorphic to the second graph.

```
{graph1, graph2} = {GraphData[{7, 172}], GraphData[{7, 172}, "ComplementGraph"]};

(* first approach *)
graph1Complement1 = GraphComplement[graph1]
```

[image]

```
(* second approach *)
graph1Complement2 = With[{adj = AdjacencyMatrix[graph1]}, 
    AdjacencyGraph[1 - IdentityMatrix[Length[adj]] - adj]
]
```

[image]

Both are isomorphic to `graph2`:

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[graph1Complement1, graph2]
(* True *)

IsomorphicGraphQ[graph1Complement2, graph2]
(* True *)
```

---

As mentioned by Feyre, the drawing of the graphs does not make it obvious that `graph2` is the complement of `graph1`. In particular, it cannot be easily seen that one of the vertex is of degree 5,

```
VertexDegree[graph2]
(* {3, 3, 1, 0, 4, 4, 5} *)
```

This is however clearer in the drawing of `graph1Complement1`.

Comment: I think there are 11 edges in the first graph and 9 edges in the second graph.  If they are complementary there would be a total of 21.  Right?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer There are 10 edges in the second graph. The drawing does not make it clear, but it can be seen in `graph1Complement1`.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Or otherwise with `EdgeCount[graph2]`.

Comment: Yes Thank you. You are quite right.  I should have taken more time to read your response.  Thanks again.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Glad this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In's an unfortunate rendering I think because the connection between what according to the `AdjacencyMatrix[]` are `6` and `7` isn't obvious.

But please consider the following mapping:

[image]